# ASCII values in JAVA

Tags: java, ascii

When I am running the below code, for any number,  it will give the ASCII value.  My question is that the ASCII values are 0-255, but how does it return the ASCII value above 255?

```java
int i=345;
System.out.println((char)i);
```

Output :

```
ř
```

Please specify how to convert the above resultant (i.e.`ř`) into it's appropirate number (i.e.`345`).

Comment: `char`s are 16-bit Unicode, not ASCII -- see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html

Comment: Thak you. you mean for any integer value it will give the uni code char na?. but when i am trying to create a unicode file to save these chars by using java, some of the chars are missing in the saved file..

Answer (score 5):

Java does not use ASCII.

`ř` is **Unicode** code point 345.

Comment: ya but some unicode values are not saving when i am creating unicode file with java

Comment: You need to understand how Unicode works.   http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html  http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: A small doubt. Will it give the unicode values for 0 to 255? or for >255?

Comment: Yes.  Casting any `char` to `int` will give its Unicode code point.  Note that `char` cannot represent non-BMP characters.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the second part of your question, cast the `char` as an `int`:

```
System.out.println("The code for 'ř' is " + (int)'ř');
```

gives

```
The code for 'ř' is 345
```